# QueryDsl-SQL: update with join (not using subqueries)

Tags: java, database, querydsl

I am using queryDsl-Sql I need to do an update statement with a join clause like:

```
update MY_TABLE t1 set t1.MY_FIELD = 'SOME_VALUE' 
                JOIN MY_TABLE_2 t2 ON t1.FIELD_WITH_FK = t2.ID
                where t2.OTHER_FIELD=12324556789 AND t2.OTHER_FIELD like '%something%'
```

Unfortunately, on queryDsl I was only able to do subqueries during update but not joins:

```
dsl.update(table1)
                .set(my_field, "SOME_VALUE")
                .where(
                     field_with_fk.in(
                          dsl.select(id).from(table2).where(other_field.eq(12324556789))
                     , fieldName.like("%something%"));
```

Which is translated to a subquery (as expected) and happens to take much much more time (difference between 10 seconds using joins and more than 1h using subselects)

I have seen that on JPAUpdateClause is possible to do so but I am not using QueryDsl-jpa here. QueryDSL-SQL has only SqlUpdateClause and I was not able to find how to join different tables when using It.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is more a workaround than a solution, but maybe helps
also others:

```
dsl.update(table1)
   .set(field1, myValue)
   .addFlag(
      QueryFlag.Position.START_OVERRIDE, //it replaces update by update with join 
      Expressions.stringTemplate("update {0} join {1} on {2} = {3} #", // I need # to ignore table1 otherwise incorrect SQL
         table1, table2, table1FieldWithFkToTable2, table2Id))
   .where(other_field.eq(12324556789), fieldName.like("%something%"));
```

this generates the following SQL:

```
update table1 join table2 on table1FieldWithFkToTable2 = table2Id #table1
set field1 = myValue
where other_field=12324556789 and fieldName like '%something%'
```